# Configure MySQL connection in Openshift

Tags: java, mysql, openshift

I am new in Openshift, and I have one question.

I was able to create the database through "phpMyAdmin", but now, I am not able to connect to it.

The error I am getting, when I try to connect to the database is the following:
**javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:321)**

My libraries directories are well defined in my Eclipse Project.
See image below:

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Thanks in advance,
Emanuel

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the MySQL JDBC driver from your classpath.

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Either download this and add this to your application classpath or add the Maven dependency to your build file.

Comment: You're not very precise in describing where "your classpath" is. It's exactly this ambiguity where starters fall over. And no, it's in this particular case definitely not the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder.

Comment: @BalusC I would hope that anybody who is brand new to Java web application development would take a few hours to sit down and understand the Java classpath, or else they are doomed to fail eventually, no matter how much we bottle feed them.

Comment: I can't find the solution to this problem yet.
Has anyone any Suggestion? Thank you in advance, Emanuel

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<version>5.1.24</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by adding the connector to my `pom.xml`.

You have [download it](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) (choose platform independent) and place it in `WEB-INF/lib`.

In my case I had:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.27</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.27-bin.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```